# htaccess url rewrite how to avoid rewriting dot (.) pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

in my .htaccess I have following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomainname.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\ -]+)$ index.php?x=$1 [L]
```

what it does is rewriting mydomainname.com/page-name to mydomainname.com/index.php?x=page-name

my problem is that I want to be able to access pages like mydomainname.com/testpage.php without the rule activating. I don't understand why it still loads the index page when I dont have a dot in the RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your telling everything to go to the index.php file which in short is:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Try this out and lets see what happens:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomainname.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9\ -]+)$ index.php?x=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: could you explain what the different lines do? I'd like to learn.

Comment: @Paul take a look [`RewriteCond Directive`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: OP's regex is `^([A-Za-z0-9\ -]+)$` which doesn't match dot anyway.